# Tooltip width for canvas element

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, width, tooltip

I am trying to display tool tip for my canvas.  Somehow my tool tip has clear background and the text is black, which matches with my page's background.  Can you please point me to some directions?

Using the code from [jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style](http://jqueryui.com/tooltip/#custom-style) gave me a tooltip with the width as long as my canvas, which is way too long.  However, the tool tip on jqueryui.com shows up very nicely.

I am not sure where to look for in my css file.  Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: It would be helpful if you post some code demonstrating your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can style jquery UI tooltip in CSS as follows:

```
ui-tooltip{
color: #FF0000; //Change the colors as you like
background-color: #00FF00;
}
```